# Caesar cipher printing out numbers instead of decrypted Text? in C

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

So I have this caesar cipher program, however when I run it it only prints out numbers instead of the decrypted text. Anyone know what I am missing? I believe there might be something wrong in the bool solved function.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "rotUtils.h"

bool solved( char decodearr[], char dictarr[][30], int size1, int size2){

    char* compared;
    bool result = false;

    for(int j = 0; j < size2; j++){

    compared = strstr( decodearr, dictarr[j]);

    }
    if( compared != '\0'){

     result = true;

         }
    return result;

}

int decode( char codearr[], char dictarr[][30], int size1, int size2)
    {
    bool solution = false;
    int key = -50;
    char decodearr[10000];
    while(solution == false && key < 51)
    {
     for( int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        {
        if(!isspace(codearr[i]))
         {
          decodearr[i] = rotate(codearr[i], key);
          }
        else
          decodearr[i] = codearr[i];


    }

    solution = solved( decodearr, dictarr, size1, size2);
    if( solution == false)
     {
      key++;
      }
    }
  for( int j = 0; j < size1; j++)
    {
    codearr[j] = decodearr[j];
    }
  return key;
}

    int main( int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    char* file = argv[1];
    char* dictionary = argv[2];
    char code[10000];
    char dict[30000][30];
    FILE* codeFile;
    codeFile = fopen(file, "r");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int key;
    FILE* dictFile;
    dictFile = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    while(!feof(codeFile))
    {
    code[i] = fgetc(codeFile);
    i++;
    }

    code[ i + 1] = '\0';
    fclose(codeFile);

    while(!feof(dictFile))
    {
    fscanf(dictFile, "%s", dict[j]);
    j++;
    }

    key = decode(code, dict, i, j);
    fclose(dictFile);

        for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
        printf("%d", code[k]);
        }

    printf( "\nThe key is: %d\n", key);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("%d", code[k]);` means "print out the decimal digits that represent the integer `code[k]`".

If you want "print out the character that represents the integer `code[k]`, then you'd want the `%c` format specifier instead: `printf("%c", code[k]);`

Comment: Wow thanks! I also have a question, do you see anything wrong in this code that might hinder it from printing out the decrypted text? Now, for some reason it does print out the text but its all random letters and symbols. Any input would help. Thanks !

Comment: `code[ i + 1] = '\0';` looks mighty suspicious, considering `i` is incremented after the previous character is assigned. Perhaps you meant `code[i] = '\0';`? Aside from that, there are chunks of this program which I can't see

Answer (score 1):

You only ever print numbers

```
 printf("%d", code[k]);
```

perhaps try

```
printf("%c", code[k]);
```

which prints the character that number represents.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `"%c"` instead of `"%d"` in your code when you want to print `code[k]`.
Good luck!